# cancel lodash debounce after promise await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, es6-promise

I have an input that calls api for results. I kept debounce so that only after particular time api will get invoked. This is working fine. However i want to reset the results after textinput text is empty. By the time textinput is empty a promise has already called and returning the result. Here is my jsfiddle link. I have used one flag abort but that flag value is not updating because as the function is in event loop.
Here is my jsfiddle       https://jsfiddle.net/foya6gc1/

```
const App = () => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState('');
        const [ searchResult, setSearchResult ] = React.useState([]);
        const [ selectedWords, setSelectedWords ] = React.useState([]);
    const [searchBoxActive, setSearchBoxActive ] = React.useState('search-box');
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu ] = React.useState(false);
    let abort = false;
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffec');
    if(!searchText) { 
      console.log('useeffect', searchText);
      setSearchResult([]);
      handleSearch.cancel();
    }
    }, [searchText]);
    const handleChange =  async e => {
     setSearchText(e.target.value);
     console.log('entered text', e.target.value);
     if(!e.target.value) {
     abort = true;
        setSearchResult([]);
      console.log('abort before', abort);
      handleSearch.cancel();
     }else {
     abort = false;
      console.log('abort before2', abort);
          handleSearch(e.target.value);

     }
    
    }
   
 const handleSearch = _.debounce(async term => {
 console.log('enter debounce');
                 const result = await getSuggestions(term);
                    console.log('abort', abort);

              if(abort) { //Here abort is always coming as false
              setSearchResult([]);
              return;
              }

     console.log('searchText',searchText);
      if(!searchText) return;
     setSearchResult(result);
    }, 300, {
  leading: true,
  trailing: false
});
   
    const handleSelect = word => {
      const newWords = [...selectedWords, word];
      setSelectedWords(newWords);
      setSearchText('');
      setSearchResult([]);
    }
    
    const handleFocusIn = () => {
        setSearchBoxActive('search-box active');
      setShowMenu(true);
    }
     const handleFocusOut = () => {
        setSearchBoxActive('search-box');
      setShowMenu(false);
    }
    return (<div>
       <div className={searchBoxActive}>
      <div className="search-control">
        
         {selectedWords.map(word => 
         <div className="css-1rhbuit-multiValue">
            <div className="css-12jo7m5">{word}</div>
           
          </div>)}
        
       
        <div className="input-wrap">
           <input type="text" value={searchText} 
           onFocus={handleFocusIn}
           onBlur={handleFocusOut}
           onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {showMenu && <div className="search-results">
      {searchResult.length > 0 ? <ul>
        {
        searchResult.map(result => <li onClick={() => handleSelect(result)}>{result}</li>)
        }
       
      </ul> :  'No Result'}
    </div> }
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using ref. I am checking the input value if it is empty then reset the results.

https://jsfiddle.net/foya6gc1/1/

```
if(!inputRef.current.value) {
                  setSearchResult([]);
                  return;
                  }
```